# Facebook Connect Implementation - What if FB user changes email?

Tags: authentication, facebook

I've implemented FB connect on my application, and all works fine.

The procedure is pretty standard:

- user authorizes the app
- user is redirected to my website
- I capture the user's FB id, email, name
- I create a new unique user in my database using this info

However I am wondering if the user leaves my site, and changes their email on FB.

The next time they visit my site, their new email would not be updated, as it was created the first time they visited.

In order to update their email address every time they visit, I would need to pull the token from the cookie every time they visit, and run an update on all their info on the database (even if it hasn't changed).

This is an incomplete solution, though. My app is designed to send email alerts to users.

If they saved a bunch of email alerts, left my site and then changed their email on FB, the email alerts would be sent to the wrong address until they visited my site again.

Some trivial options include alerting the user on the front end about the limitation of using FB connect, living with it, or abandoning this login method altogether.

Does anyone have more intelligent ideas on how to solve this pickle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative method, I would look into using [real-time updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/) for [users](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), which will let Facebook tell *you* when your users change any of their information, and in that, their e-mail address. This is more efficient than polling because you're only doing processing when data is received, and more user-friendly because you're not asking for that scary `offline_access` token. In practice, I've found that the real-time updates are sort of hard to work with, but if executed properly they could do exactly what you're asking for here.

Comment: Good catch - They didn't have this the last time I was mucking with the facebook API (it's been a while).

Comment: Yeah, it's like a lot of other features on the Facebook API - a good idea, could be executed much better. But I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: thanks @jimmy - seems to be a pretty good alternative - is this something you would also run via cron?

Comment: @torr no, actually you set up a receiver script which is available to the web. When Facebook has data to send you, it sends you data via a POST request to that script and your script handles it from there, whether it's updating your database, sending you an e-mail, whatever. No cron required, so you're never doing empty updates.

Comment: ok - they FB provides some sample code [here](https://github.com/facebook/real-time/blob/master/samples/php/callback.php) -- if you have some other scripts to suggest please let me know

Comment: Any better solutions to this? The real-time updates aren't in use by Facebook any longer.

Answer (score 2):

Since Facebook isn't going to notify you when a user changes their email, then yes, you'd need to poll/check it.

Either check each time the user visits your site or have the users grant you the `offline_access` permission so you get a non-expiring token. With that you could batch query your users on a regular basis to see if they have changed their email addy on facebook (You would of course need to store this token for each user).

Comment: right, the `offline_access` token -- good idea -- then run a cron job on the Facebook IDs polling for changes -- would this be a good strategy?

Comment: Yup, that would fly. To optimize it you could do both (check and poll), only polling when a user hasn't visited your site for X amount of time.

Comment: @torr - see @Jimmy Sawczuk answer below - I wasn't aware they actually DO have a notification system now.